# SSRS 2008 Contains()

Tags: ssrs-2008

In SSRS 2008, I am trying to add a group expression based on the data containing the word "HOLD".   Here is what I have currently.

=IIF(Fields!NOTE.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("HOLD"), "Z-HOLD", Fields!DROPZONE.Value)

This is not working.  Any ideas on what I have done wrong would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Simple mistake, you're converting the source string to a lower:

```
=IIF(Fields!NOTE.Value.ToLowerInvariant()
```

But then you're comparing it with an upper string:

```
.Contains("HOLD")
```

Try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!NOTE.Value.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("hold"), "Z-HOLD", Fields!DROPZONE.Value)
```

Comment: Mispost  - double post